# How to refresh page after delete or update item data in Ionic-V3

Tags: ionic3

I want to refresh my page after deleting or updating an item. 
Actually, I searched and found a solution but with this, reload taking 5 seconds.

```
window.location.reload();
```

So I want to make it easy like I click on delete or update the refresh page in less time..anyone knows how to do?

Comment: Update your question with the code of your ionic page.

Answer (score 0):

With ionic(probably Angular) you want to make SPA(single page application), means you shouldn't use location.reload at all.

So basically you should have model in your Component - something like `items: Array[]`, then in your html - bind to this data, something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"...>...</div>
```

When you update your (update data or remove) model data, Angular change detection will notice that and rebuild view itself.

Angular has good [doc](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2)

Comment: Ionic is not meant to do SPAs (https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation). However you are right for the change detection.

Comment: @AugustinR well, ionic navigation is ionic's Angular router with some additional forward/back methods, so your page might not reload completely, only needed router-outlet sections. It's still SPA, but i agree, you can create any kind of application with Ionic/Angular.